# how to upload an image to a wwwroot folder that stores in a SQL server

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I'm loading images which are store in the database and I want to upload them to the serverpath which is in wwwroot folder.

```
byte[] imageData= //Loading image from sql server

string strWebPath = _hostingEnvironment.WebRootPath + "\\img\\+"This is where I want to upload that image"";
```

How can I upload that image into wwwroot/img folder

Comment: Can you get the image name?

Comment: Yeah i can get image name from sql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Storing image datas in the database is not the best way.

Anyway, if you have your image data in a byte array, you can store it anywhere using a filestream.

You need to add : using System.IO;

```
        byte[] imageData = ...//Loading image from sql server
        string strWebPath = _hostingEnvironment.WebRootPath + "\\img\\myImageName.png"; //yourImageName.Extension;


        //You may have to change the FileMode.Create according the image names if, unique etc.
        using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(strWebPath, FileMode.Create))
        {
            //Takes a byte array, writes to the disk from the given index until the given length.
            fs.Write(imageData, 0, imageData.Length);
            fs.Flush();
        }
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: I have no option but to load images from my database for some reason. I will try to implement your my code.

Answer (score 1):

In most cases, files are stored in the database as byte[]. So you can use this method to achieve it.

FileModel:

```
public class AppFile
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string FileName { get; set; }
        public byte[] Content { get; set; }
    }
```

Method:

```
public async Task Uploadfilefromdb(int id)
        {
            //select file by id
            var result =await _dbcontext.File.FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Id == id);
            var fileName = Path.GetFileName(result.FileName);
            var filePath = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), @"wwwroot\images",fileName);

            using (var fileStream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create))
            {
                //convert byte[] to IformFile
                var stream = new MemoryStream(result.Content);
                IFormFile file = new FormFile(stream, 0, result.Content.Length, "name", fileName);

                await file.CopyToAsync(fileStream);
            }
        }
```

Demo:

[image]

After I use this method, image has been uploaded from database to `wwwroot`.

[image]